# What response header do I set in order to let the browser know to always use the cache?

Tags: javascript, html, caching, browser

I want the browser to use the cache. Always.

What header so I set? Cache-Control? Etag? Which one?

What would the value be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check next headers:

```
Cache-Control
Date
Expires
Pragma
```

For example:
Next create private "one week" cache (only on client, no cache on proxy or gateways):

```
Cache-Control:private
Date:Wed, 24 Aug 2011 07:06:04 GMT
Expires:Wed, 31 Aug 2011 07:06:04 GMT
```

Next create no cache:

```
Cache-Control:no-cache
Date:Wed, 24 Aug 2011 08:47:15 GMT
Expires:-1
Pragma:no-cache
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this:

http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs